# Always says "No dashboards are active for the current data set" when activating Tensorboard

Tags: macos, tensorflow, tensorboard

I am using Python 3.7.3 in macOS system in Anaconda environment. Tensorflow (1.14.0), Matplotlib (3.1.0) and other modules were installed there and everything worked fine. I wrote the following codes and run it.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def add_layer(inputs, inputs_size, outputs_size,activation_function = None):
    with tf.name_scope('layer'):
        with tf.name_scope('weight'):
            Weights = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([inputs_size, outputs_size]))        
        with tf.name_scope('biase'):
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,outputs_size])+0.1)
        with tf.name_scope('wx_plus_b'):
            Wx_plus_b = tf.matmul(inputs, Weights) + biases
        if activation_function == None:outputs = Wx_plus_b
        else: outputs = activation_function(Wx_plus_b)
        return outputs

'''
multiple lines omitted here
'''

writer = tf.compat.v1.summary.FileWriter("logs/",sess.graph)
```

I can see a local file with name

```py
"events.out.tfevents.1561289962.Botaos-MacBook-Pro.local"
```

generated in "logs/" folder. I opened terminal and cd to that folder with Anaconda environment activated. Then I typed

```py
"python -m tensorboard.main --logdir=‘logs/‘ --host localhost --port 6006"
```

and got response

```py
TensorBoard 1.14.0 at http://localhost:6006/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Then no matter I use safari or chrome to open "http://localhost:6006/", there's always nothing shown except "No dashboards are active for the current data set."
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3FQa.png)
Actually I also tried other commends such as

```py
python -m tensorboard.main --logd logs --host localhost --port 6006
```

```py
python -m tensorboard.main --logd logs --host localhost --port 6006
```

But there's no difference.

The original codes as follows:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def add_layer(inputs, inputs_size, outputs_size,activation_function = None):
    with tf.name_scope('layer'):
        with tf.name_scope('weight'):
            Weights = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([inputs_size, outputs_size]))        
        with tf.name_scope('biase'):
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,outputs_size])+0.1)
        with tf.name_scope('wx_plus_b'):
            Wx_plus_b = tf.matmul(inputs, Weights) + biases
        if activation_function == None:outputs = Wx_plus_b
        else: outputs = activation_function(Wx_plus_b)
        return outputs
x_data = np.linspace(-1,1,300,dtype = np.float32)[:,np.newaxis] 
noise = np.random.normal(0,0.05,x_data.shape).astype(np.float32)    
y_data = np.square(x_data) - 0.5 + noise

with tf.name_scope('inputs'):
    xs = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,1],name='x_in')
    ys = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,1],name='y_in')

l1 = add_layer(xs, 1, 10, tf.nn.relu) 

prediction = add_layer(l1, 10, 1, None)

with tf.name_scope('loss'):
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(prediction - ys),reduction_indices=[1])) #no need to do tf.sum() as in link.                  #tf.reduce_mean()
with tf.name_scope('train'):
    train_step = tf.compat.v1.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)


sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()

writer = tf.compat.v1.summary.FileWriter("logs/",sess.graph)
sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to find the logs directory while you are already in the logs directory.

try executing: tensorboard --logdir logs

from the directory containing the logs dir.